# rails - devise - undefined method `remember_created_at' when signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had devise working fine until I migrated rails from SQLite to SQL server. Migration all successful and able to log into rails. But when I click "log out" I am getting below error,

```
> NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#destroy undefined method
> `remember_created_at=' for #<User:0x00007fe169c25d10> Did you mean?
> remember_me=

    Rails.root: /home/blacklight/projects/tth-blacklight
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
    devise (4.5.0) lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb:61:in `forget_me!'
    devise (4.5.0) lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb:32:in `forget_me'
    devise (4.5.0) lib/devise/hooks/forgetable.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'
    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'
    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'
    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'
    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:263:in `block in logout'
```

db/migrate/2018..add_devise_to users.rb

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email,              null: true
    end     
     add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
  end

  def self.down
        raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

db/Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_11_15_061838) do

  create_table "bookmarks", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.string "user_type"
    t.string "document_id"
    t.string "document_type"
    t.binary "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["document_id"], name: "index_bookmarks_on_document_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookmarks_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "searches", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.binary "query_params"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "user_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_searches_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "guest", default: false
    t.string "email"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end
end
```

Not sure a what or where I have to look at. I am new to rails so simple explanation would be much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Have you run 'rails generate devise:install' and 'rails generate devise MODEL' command before running 'rails db:migrate'. Kindly check doc https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#starting-with-rails

Comment: @Anshul I run those commands when installing devise which was couple of months ago. All this while devise was working fine with rails using SQLite. I recently moved from SQLite to SQL server using rake db:migrate after which log out issue started

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if migration has actually caused the issue but I learned that *:rememberable* option within model/user.rb is responsible for creating time and managing *remember_created_at*. And I do not have remember me check box when signing in the user. So altogether I removed :rememberable option. And to make sure user get signed out after a while included the *:timeoutable* option

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the `forget_me` function in `lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb`.

Remove or comment this line:

```
self.remember_created_at = nil if self.class.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out
```

And add this line:

```
self.remember_me = nil if self.class.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out
```

It should look like this:

```
def forget_me!
  return unless persisted?
  self.remember_token = nil if respond_to?(:remember_token)
  self.remember_me = nil if self.class.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out
  #self.remember_created_at = nil if self.class.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out
  save(validate: false)
end
```